# Azure Websites vs, Cloud Services vs. Virtual Machines for WordPress Multisite

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I am having a heck of a time trying to decide between the different deployment models Azure offers for a WordPress Multisite setup. Due to the complexity of multisite, I'm thinking I will need to use virtual machines.

The site has these requirements:

1. Sub-domain multi-site will require the service to have a wildcard domain mapping so site1.example.com and site2.example.com and so on will resolve.
2. Map new SSL certificates on demand to child sites.
3. Contain 4096 databases using the [multi-DB plugin](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-db).

The first requirement for sub domains makes me think I won't be able to use Azure Websites?

Answer (score 0):

I found this article on [Convert a WordPress Site to a Multisite](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-convert-wordpress-multisite/). It doesn't seem feasible to have to add each domain to the Website.

```
If a domain is not listed here, it will not be available for mapping inside 
WordPress, regardless of how the domain DNS is setup.
```